# How to do box-whisker plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have

```
num city    inc pop edu crime   cult
1,0 Moscow  29343,00    8683,00 0,00    10,40   0,00
2,0 Paris    25896,00   17496,00    0,00    10,20   1,00
3,0 London    21785,00  15063,00    0,00    14,20   1,00
4,0 Berlin    20000,00  70453,00    1,00    18,00   1,00
```

I try to do `box-whisker` plot with

```
desire_salary = (df[(df['inc'] <= int(salary_people))])
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')
result.plot.boxplot(ax=axarr[1, 1])
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'SeriesPlotMethods' object has no attribute 'boxplot'`
What's wrong?

Comment: and how did you come up with this call? Doc clearly states its `result.boxplot`

Comment: @lejlot `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'`

Comment: @lejlot, i try to convert it to datafra,e, but it's don't work

Comment: what do you get if you print `result `? Is it a series or df?

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: @Yarnspinner, now result is series

Comment: @tom, pandas is 0.18.1

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')` has only one value, `cult`, selected. The standard behavior of `pivot_table` is to return a `series` when the pivot_table has only one value/one column. However, the `series` object has no `boxplot` method so we must first change it to a dataframe.

There are two ways of changing your series to a dataframe:

1) Entering a `list` (even though theres only a single value) into the `pivot_table` argument before creating the `pivot_table`

```
result = df.pivot_table(index='city', values=['cult'], aggfunc='count')
df2.boxplot()
```

2) Calling the `to_frame()` method after creating a `series` in `pivot_table`

```
result = desire_salary.pivot_table(values = 'cult', index = 'city', aggfunc='count')
result.to_frame().boxplot()
```